# Add New Series to Chart from a Different Sheet (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, charts, range, series

I am new to VBA and trying to create a macro that uses Data from Sheet A to create a Chart in Sheet B.
Here is my code so far:

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Sheets("Projekte_RK").Activate

ProjectRow = 6
ProjectCol = 3
sumCol = 2

' evaluate travel cost sums to include only those over 1000 Euro
If Evaluate(Sheets("Projekte_RK").Cells(ProjectRow, sumCol).Formula) > 1000 Then
    MsgBox Evaluate(Sheets("Projekte_RK").Cells(ProjectRow, sumCol).Formula)
    Sheets("Auswertung").Activate
    Sheets("Auswertung").ChartObjects(2).Activate

' create new series for the projects with over 1000 Euro travel costs
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Cells(ProjectRow, ProjectCol)

        .Values = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range(Cells(ProjectRow, 4), Cells(ProjectRow, 32))
        .XValues = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3, 32))
        '.Values = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range("D6:AF6")
        '.XValues = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range("D3:AF3")
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "hello world"
End If


End Sub
```

When I execute it I get a run-time error 1004 (Application defined or object defined error) in the lines:

```
.Values = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range(Cells(ProjectRow, 4), Cells(ProjectRow, 32))
.XValues = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3, 32))
```

As such, Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range(Cells(ProjectRow, 4), Cells(ProjectRow, 32)) works if the corresponding sheet is active, which is not possible in my code though, since I have to activate the chart to add values.

It runs perfectly if I substitute the part where I get the error with

```
    .Values = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range("D6:AF6")
    .XValues = Sheets("Projekte_RK").Range("D3:AF3")
```

However I need the variable refences to the cells to loop through other rows (not yet implemented).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: When you use `Range()` and/or `Cells()` you should always qualify them with a worksheet reference, otherwise they will default to the ActiveSheet. So `sht.Range(sht.Cells(1,1),sht.Cells(10,10))` and not just `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(10,10))` In this case your code is failing because you're trying to get a Range from "Projekte_RK", but the unqualified `Cells()` are referring to the active sheet.